# List of all bookings in the next 3 days

Tags: 7, views, datetime

In a content type i have a field date which has a start date and end date. using views i want to put filter in such a way that it display results in a date range form now to next 3 days. In a fields i can see content:dates and in filter i can see start and end like this.[image]

After selecting content:start date i dont know waht to do screen shot like this[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your "Date selection" in your second screenshot to "Text". If I remember correctly, you can now provide a text as paramaters.
There you can add things like 
`from: now` and `till: now +3 days`

Comment: ok after selecting text i see only starting year and ending year option http://i.imgur.com/ax4kldP.png like this should i enter 'from:now' here

Comment: Just provide `now` and `now +3 days` for the starting- and ending year respectively. I'm not sure where to add the space between the `+` and `3` so you might want to play with that...